# Not able to add attribute on page OnInit

Tags: telerik

I have a radbutton with the name "rbtnDelete".Here i am trying to register below code on page OnInit method

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "ConfirmDelete", 
                                                objUtl.RadConfirmDelete(),true);
this.rbtnDelete.Attributes.Add("OnClientClicking",
"function(sender,args){ConfirmDelete(sender, args, 'dgvContactList',
'hidContactRowCount');}");
```

.But it is not working. But if i try to use in aspx with this code it is working fine

```
OnClientClicking="function(sender,args)
{
   ConfirmDelete(sender,args,'dgvContactList','hidContactRowCount');
}"
```

Answer (score 1):

OnClientClicking is an AJAX event of a JavaScript class representing the RadButton, not a standard DOM event.  The approach you used would work great if a DOM event (as in my second example below), but since Telerik has an AJAX API, you should be able to do instead:

```
this.rbtnDelete.OnClientClicking = 
"function(sender,args){ConfirmDelete(sender, args, 
    'dgvContactList','hidContactRowCount');}";
```

The DOM-specific way is this:

```
this.rbtnDelete.Attributes.Add("onclick",
"function(sender,args){ConfirmDelete(sender, args, 'dgvContactList',
'hidContactRowCount');}");
```

If you do the latter, you have to stop propagation of a form submission.  For the former, this would be the better option.